# Swipe Gesture with Custom Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, swipe, gesture

I am currently using a modal segue in my storyboard to go from one view to another with a button. And on the way back I am using a button to run a custom segue with my ABCustomSegue. It is all working fine I just want to be able to run this custom segue after the user preforms a swipe. How might I achieve that?

ABCustomSegue:

```
-(void)perform{
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
    [destinationViewController.view setFrame:sourceViewController.view.window.frame];
    [destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -sourceViewController.view.frame.size.height)];
    [destinationViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                     animations:^{
                         [destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)];
                         [destinationViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
                     }];
}
```

Current Swipe Recognizer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeBack:)];
    bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeTop;
    bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:bezelSwipeGestureRecognizer];

    UIView *invisibleScrollPreventer = [UIView new];
    invisibleScrollPreventer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:invisibleScrollPreventer];

}

-(void)swipeBack:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        NSLog(@"swipe back");

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```